# Closing MDI child

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

hi currently i am working on a MDI application.In this application my main form is the MDI Parent form. through whihc i go to the MDI Child.now when all the functionalities in the child form is done there is a messagebox and on the OK click of the messagebox my Child form should close and i should go to the main form.My child form is closing.but what is happening is for getting to the main form i am creating a new instance of the parent form.So there are like 2 Main forms open.
Here is the code please help.

```
private void btnsave_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dialogResult = 
        MessageBox.Show("record saved", "requisition", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
    {

        //frmmain main = new frmmain();
        //main.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("error", "requisition", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: just hide your MDI child and if you really don't need it anymore, destroy it

Comment: What is the context of "this". Is it the MdiChild?

Comment: There is no problem with the child form this.close() is closeing the child form. all i want is to go back to the parent form without creating a new instance of that form.

Comment: Azhar Khorasany yea its is MDichild

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is in the `MainForm`

```
using (MdiChildForm form = new MdiChildForm())
{
    form.Showdialog();
}
```

To close the `MdiChildForm` after the `MessageBox` okay button is clicked, in some event handler you want

```
DialogResult dlgRes = MessageBox.Show("record saved", "requisition", 
    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
if (dlgRes == DialogResult.OK)
    this.Close();
```

This will return control to the `MainForm`. It is as simple as that. if you are getting two `MainForm`s, there is something you are not telling us. If the `MainForm` is hidden, that is, you do `mainForm.Hide();` at some point, then before you close the `MdiChild`, do `this.MdiParent.Show();`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: What i am doing is frmmain main=new frmmain(); main.show(); which is creating another instance of that main form.i hav written that code.

Comment: Well don't do that. Simple. When the child form closes it will return to the parent.